# ObjectOutputStream.toByteArray returns garbage

Tags: java, stream

I need to get the byte array out of everything I send to the output stream. But instead I get 4 bytes of rubbish. Why?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
objectOutputStream.write(new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
byte[] original = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(); 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(original)); // why not [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several flaws in your code. First of all you should use `writeObject()`:

```
objectOutputStream.writeObject(new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
```

then you should use symmetric `ObjectInputStream` for reading:

```
final ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
        new ByteArrayInputStream(
                byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
        )
);
byte[] original = (byte[]) objectInputStream.readObject();
```

**However** if you already have a `byte[]`, there is no point in using Java serialization to convert it to byte array (which it already is!) Just write and read it directly:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byteArrayOutputStream.write(new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9});
final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
    byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
);
final byte[] original = new byte[9];
byteArrayInputStream.read(original);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(original));
```

Answer (score 0):

An ObjectOutputStream  is not a OutputStream and if it did the same thing there wouldn't be much point in having it.

An ObjectOutputStream is used for writing Objects, it has a header (which you can see) and footer (which you can't see unless you close the stream)

Comment: OK. But for serialization I need to implement 
    public void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException, so how can I get a serialized output into byte array then?

Comment: The simplest way is to write the `byte[]` as an object which Tomasz demonstrates. This will use far more bytes than you might expect but your data will be in there and you can read it out using ObjectInputStream ;)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write anything into the objectOutputStream, but some meta information, that comes with the ObjectOutputStream.
For the purpose of your small example you can use the ByteArrayOutputStream. Then You need to write the data into the stream using byteArrayOutputStream.flush().

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byteArrayOutputStream.write(new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});
byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
byte[] original = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(); 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(original));
```

And don't forget to close the stream when you are done!

```
byteArrayOutputStream.close();
```

ObjectOutputStreams are used to serialize Objects.
If you want to serialize Objects you should use ObjectOutputStream#writeObject and ObjectInputStream#readObject.

Example : http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/